# Is is possible to create regex pattern for comma-separated list without repeating pattern for single item?

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex :)

I need regex that would match single email or number of emails that separated by commas.

To match single email I wrote `\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b`. Let's call it `pattern1`.

To match list of emails I wrote something like this

`"(" + pattern1 + ")([,]\\s*" + pattern1 + ")*"`

But because I can't use variables in Java annotations I have to write something like this

`(\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)([,]\\s*\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)*`

which looks pretty scary.

Is it possible to rewrite my regex so I don't need to copy-paste pattern for single email ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a question about the regexp, or how to implement it in a particular language?

Comment: No need to put the comma in square brackets.  You haven't specified the dialect of RE you're looking for, but as far as I know \s is not defined in BRE or ERE.  So it seems that it would be simpler to use: `"(" + pattern1 + ", *)*" + pattern1`

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it and improve the readability by using `\w` for "letters+underscores+numbers", use `\d` for numbers, and turn on case insensitive matching so you can just use `a-z` for letters:

```
(\b[\w.%-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)([,]\\s*\b[\w.%-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)*
```

and you could also maybe shorten it further with this (the comma and spaces being optional):

```
((,\\s*)?\b[\w.%-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)+
```

some code to demonstrate (using regex capture groups as well):

```
    //c#    
    string input = @"sdf.an@dfgdfg.com, sdfsdf@fdfd.erff";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"((?:,\s*)?(\b[\w.%-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b))");
    string result = "matches:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
    {
        result += "match " + i + ",value:" + matches[i].Groups[2].Value + "\n";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I was thinking about your second option too. But it implies that string may start with comma :) Is there a way to avoid it ?

Comment: it's optional though, the ? makes it give up the whole group and match the first one too. (in theory, not tested :)).  You could put your optional comma/space segment at the end too, honestly.

Comment: By the way second pattern doesn't work on `sdf.an@dfgdfg.com,   sdfsdf@fdfd.erff` because ", " in the middle doesn't match second group :)

Comment: it works, though the approach of simply splitting on a regex probably is a better idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent review of how to match an email address in RE [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).  That may be where you got the regexp in your question.

Notwithstanding the balance between "perfect" and "practical" matching, you may also need to consider valid comments within addresses.  For example, the following are all equivalent:

- user@example.com
- "Joe User" user@example.com
- <user@example.com> Joe User

That is, these are all valid entries for the To/From/CC/BCC/Reply-To line in a message.  If you're sure that your list of comma-separated addresses will not contain comment parts, then you don't have to worry about this.

That said, your "scary" regex looks right to me.  And believe me, once you're more comfortable with regular expressions, it doesn't look so scary.  Add support for comment portions of addresses, and it might be a little more daunting…   :-)

Answer (score 0):

If supported in your regex flavor, you can use sub pattern calls, like:

```
(foobar)(?,(?-1))*
```

Or more verbally like:

```
(?x)
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<foo> foobar )
)
(?&foo) (?: , (?&foo) )*
```

If the match is anchored to beginning and end of string, you could also use:

```
^(?:foobar(?:$|,(?!$)))+$
```

or

```
^(?:(?:^|(?!^),)foobar)+$
```